# css text-align overruled?

Tags: html, css, inline-styles

I have a `<div>` with `text-align:left` - inside that: a `<p>` with `text-align:center`.
The "closest" property should win = center - but it doesn't all 3 `<p>`'s are left-aligned ?!?
Same result in both Firefox and Chrome - This is how it looks in Chrome's "inspector":
[image]
NB: I can't reproduce it in a simple html-file..
Any idea what's happening here ?

EDIT: Found it finally: I'd hyphenated (those damn invisible shy's) a little too thoroughly...

Comment: Are you using js in this file or is the text align: center inline css?
The "closet" is the inline style="text-align: center"

Comment: They are both inline - "produced" with JS (a string) and then inserted into a container-div

Comment: Your div is only 72px wide - maybe it is actually being centered but just not too apparent.

Comment: Hm.. There's several lines - the shorter are also left-aligned...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was "silent hyphens" (& shy;) in my CSS.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've shown us, it doesn't make sense. But I'm going to guess that, somewhere in a CSS file, there is something like:

```
p {text-align: left !important;}
```

Comment: Wrong, you can see in the inspector `element.style` is overruled. This kind of inline css already override any distant CSS. It should come from some JS code I guess.

Comment: Nope - a `!important` rule will even override locally applied styles like this one.

Comment: @T4NK3R What happens if you just remove the `text-align:left` from the containing `<div>`? Since all of its children are block-level elements with a specific `text-align`, it's kind of redundant.

Comment: @Kolink - Then it's centered. (There IS no !important) What about the "Unknown property name" message ?

Comment: Did you notice the `unknown property name` ? Could it have some special generated chars in "text-align" ? Try to rewrite it manually

Comment: @samsamX The html is delivered by CKeditor.. But I tried different kinds of alignment (right + justify) - both get overruled too - yet both work fine if the [div] doesn't have it's text-align:left. VERY strange..

Comment: @Kolink - no it's not redundant. If there's no specific alignment of the [p]'s I WANT them to inherit left from the parent-[div] - since that in turn inherits center from it's parent - this is deep : )